# Replacing 11.10 gnome power manager with 11.04 or XFCE power manager

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, power-management, xfce, gnome-power-manager

I am not too keen on the new 11.10 power manager control - there are less options I can tweak.

Does anyone know how to replace the 11.10 gnome power manager/control with the one that comes with 11.04 or even with XFCE power manager?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Which are the options that you need?
There are things configurable but not shown in the configuration dialog, for example to remove the automatic dimming of monitor's backlight you can write in the terminal:

`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim-battery false`

To see all the configuration keys avalable use:

`gsettings list-keys org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`

Comment: Thank you. But I looked into that through dconf-editor.I am looking for example (1)"only display an icon when charging or discharging" - otherwise no icon (2)and when on battery, i am looking for options such as "reduce backlight brightness" but not "display dim when idle" and "spin down harddisk" (3)when on AC, I can set my own "display brightness" and "dim display when idle" - These are all available  in power manager 2.32 (Natty)- They seem to take many of the options away and under the "Screen" setting in Oneiric, it is not intuitive at all.Don't they have separate setting for AC and batt?